# virtual value total_price is saved as 1 instead of total price number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

`total_price` of all products in `cart` is not saving as it should be. it shows always 1, no matter what the total price actually is. this problem got in after installing the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) and [google_currency gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency) so I can change the price itself of the product based on locale selected not only the currency.

so the total price is always 1, but at the same time the amount of money that I have on screen during the shopping process shows the right number,I mean if I select 2 products with price A and B, then in cart (on screen) I have the right total_price = A+B.. more than this, when I press to create the order after I fill in the fields for credit card, the ActiveMerchant sends the data to paypal and the amount of USD that goes to paypal is the total_price that I have in cart A+B..

**the problem is:** why the app takes the right `total_price` and sends it to paypal, but at the same time can not store this `total_price` in the database on order create, it saves 1 instead.

what **console** says when I create **order**:

```
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `orders` (`card_expires_on`, `card_type`, `cart_id`, `created_at`, `first_name`, `ip_address`, `last_name`, `total`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-04-01', 'visa', 5, '2012-04-18 21:35:38', 'Rosca', '127.0.0.1', 'Sergiu', 1, '2012-04-18 21:35:38', 7)
```

**order_transaction** details:

```
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `order_transactions` (`action`, `amount`, `authorization`, `created_at`, `message`, `order_id`, `params`, `success`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('purchase', 1, '0GT41652PP785722H', '2012-04-18 21:35:46', 'Success', 5, '--- \nbuild: \"2764190\"\nAck: Success\ntimestamp: \"2012-04-18T21:35:45Z\"\nTransactionID: 0GT41652PP785722H\namount: \"42.00\"\namount_currency_id: USD\ntransaction_id: 0GT41652PP785722H\nack: Success\nBuild: \"2764190\"\navs_code: X\nversion: \"62.0\"\nTimestamp: \"2012-04-18T21:35:45Z\"\nCorrelationID: 690aa904db3c\nAmount: \"42.00\"\nAVSCode: X\nVersion: \"62.0\"\ncvv2_code: M\nCVV2Code: M\ncorrelation_id: 690aa904db3c\n', 1, '2012-04-18 21:35:46')
```

a few details on how the order is created:

**orders_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.total = current_cart.total_price
#    raise current_cart.total_price.inspect
    @order.line_items = current_cart.line_items
    @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil
      else
        render :action => "failure"
      end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to products_path, :notice => 
          'Thank you for your order.' }
          format.json { render :json => @order }
        end
    else
       render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

**note** if I activate the raise inspect line in controller I get

`#<Money cents:4200 currency:USD>`  error, where 4200 is total_price for 2 selected products in this case. 42.00 USD.
this is one more evidence that total_price formula works fine up to the point when the app needs to store it in the database.

**Total price:**

`total_price` is formed in **cart.rb** and **line_item.rb**

**line_item.rb**

```
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :user

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
```

**cart.rb**

```
has_many :line_items#, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :order

  def to_s
    id
  end

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(:product_id => product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end
```

**EDIT**

the `order.total` field type in database is now integer(11), but I tried the decimal(10,0) to store the price in cents and it didn't work anyway, I got always total price of 1USD. the price for `products` are decimal(10,0).

really big **thank you** for helping.. might be useful for future developers that got into this.

Any other information you might need, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed the field of `order.total` from `decimal` to `float` type and it is working now fine. I have the right amount sent to paypal, and the right amount in the orders created for the user. Before using `money gem` it was working well with `decimal` field type.